# Display two td per row

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here my code for retrieve data and want to display them into a table. As specific where each row should only contain two td with the data.

```
//seelct forklft query
    $select_part_query = "SELECT DISTINCT part_code, part_desc, part_size, oem, part_image FROM tblpartDetails WHERE part_code LIKE '%$txtSearch%' OR part_desc LIKE '%$txtSearch%' OR part_size LIKE '%$txtSearch%' OR oem LIKE '%$txtSearch%'";

    $result1 = mysqli_query ($mydatabase, $select_part_query);
                if($result1)
                {
                    $counter1 = 1;
                    while($info1 = mysqli_fetch_array( $result1 )) 
                    {
                        if( $counter1 == 1 )
                        {
                            echo "<tr>";
                        }
                            echo '<td style="width:460px; padding:15px;">';
                                echo "<div style='width:430px; height:210px; padding:10px; background-color:rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.8);box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.8);'>";
                                    echo "<div style='float:left'>";
                                        echo "<img src=".$info1['part_image'] ." width=210px height=210px ></img>";
                                    echo "</div>";

                                    echo "<div style='width:220px; height:200px; margin-left:210px; padding-left:10px'>";
                                        echo "<p class='txtCode' title='Part'>".$info1['part_code']."</p>";
                                        echo "<p>".$info1['part_desc']."</p>"; 
                                        echo "<div id='btnView' style='width:100px; margin-top:100px; margin-left:120px;'>";
                                            echo "<img src='images/view-detail.png' width='100px' height='40px'/>";
                                        echo "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            echo "</td>";
                        if( $counter1 >= 2)
                        {
                             echo"</tr>";
                        }else{

                        $counter1++;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The result of this process should like this:

```
=============     =============
|           |     |           |
|   Item 1  |     |   Item 2  |
|           |     |           |
=============     =============

=============     =============
|           |     |           |
|   Item 3  |     |   Item 4  |
|           |     |           |
=============     =============

=============
|           |
|   Item 5  | 
|           |
=============

=============
|           |
|   Item 6  | 
|           |
=============

=============
|           |
|   Item 7  | 
|           |
=============
```

Comment: Why is item 6 not next to item 5 in your desired output? What logic are you wanting to use to determine the arrangement?

Comment: @MikeBrant  Yes.This code I reference and modified used in my condition. I want to make each row consist two <td> and display my result in each of the <td>. At the beginning it process correctly..but till the next row it display like this.

Comment: Your question says the result of the process should like like that unbalanced arrangement where item 6 is below item 5. Are you saying now that they should be side by side? If so, you should revise your question, as it is unclear.

Comment: @MikeBrant  Sorry for my unclear information. But I tried to edit it, but it keep alert me add more detail information on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second condition should be compared with **if( $counter1%2==1)**

```
$result1 = mysqli_query ($mydatabase, $select_part_query);
            if($result1)
            {
                $counter1 = 0;
                while($info1 = mysqli_fetch_array( $result1 )) 
                {
                    if( $counter1%2==0 )
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                    }
                        echo '<td style="width:460px; padding:15px;">';
                            echo "<div style='width:430px; height:210px; padding:10px; background-color:rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.8);box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.8);'>";
                                echo "<div style='float:left'>";
                                    echo "<img src=".$info1['part_image'] ." width=210px height=210px ></img>";
                                echo "</div>";

                                echo "<div style='width:220px; height:200px; margin-left:210px; padding-left:10px'>";
                                    echo "<p class='txtCode' title='Part'>".$info1['part_code']."</p>";
                                    echo "<p>".$info1['part_desc']."</p>"; 
                                    echo "<div id='btnView' style='width:100px; margin-top:100px; margin-left:120px;'>";
                                        echo "<img src='images/view-detail.png' width='100px' height='40px'/>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            echo "</div>";
                        echo "</td>";
                    if( $counter1%2==1)
                    {
                         echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    $counter1++;

                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks you..your solution is workable with perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code:

```
$select_part_query = "SELECT DISTINCT part_code, part_desc, part_size, oem, part_image FROM tblpartDetails WHERE part_code LIKE '%$txtSearch%' OR part_desc LIKE '%$txtSearch%' OR part_size LIKE '%$txtSearch%' OR oem LIKE '%$txtSearch%'";

    $result1 = mysqli_query ($mydatabase, $select_part_query);
                if($result1)
                {
                    $counter1 = 0;
                    while($info1 = mysqli_fetch_array( $result1 )) 
                    {
                        if( $counter1%2==0 )
                        {
                            echo "<tr>";
                        }
                            echo '<td style="width:460px; padding:15px;">';
                                echo "<div style='width:430px; height:210px; padding:10px; background-color:rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.8);box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.8);'>";
                                    echo "<div style='float:left'>";
                                        echo "<img src=".$info1['part_image'] ." width=210px height=210px ></img>";
                                    echo "</div>";

                                    echo "<div style='width:220px; height:200px; margin-left:210px; padding-left:10px'>";
                                        echo "<p class='txtCode' title='Part'>".$info1['part_code']."</p>";
                                        echo "<p>".$info1['part_desc']."</p>"; 
                                        echo "<div id='btnView' style='width:100px; margin-top:100px; margin-left:120px;'>";
                                            echo "<img src='images/view-detail.png' width='100px' height='40px'/>";
                                        echo "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            echo "</td>";
                        if( $counter1%2==0)
                        {
                             echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        $counter1++;

                    }
                }
```